# How much does compiling degrade an SSD?

Tags: compilation, hard-drive, solid-state-drive

I am one who presses Ctrl+S while coding a lot (reflex) and I recompile my code often as my code-base usually not very large. So I sometimes even hard-code parameters and change them then recompile.
Is my style insignificant to the degradation of my SSD or should I move compilation to a magnetic hard-drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not worry. SSD endurance is quite good. Endurance is measured in Disk full Writes Per Day (DWPD). Modern SSDs should have at least 0.5 DWPD / 3 years. It means Drive can cope with 50% full capacity write per day for the continuous period of 3 years. Manipulations with code (Edit, Save, Compile) would barely perform even 1% full capacity write per day. Check SMART Health Data of your SSD. It has parameter called Life-time left in percentage. It will help to understand the use in your case.